# How to count data in pandas dataframe under a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am using a retail dataset with product sales of 70+ products across 13 stores. The data shows how many of a specific item was purchased in a particular week.

I have created a function that allows me to create a new dataframe for each partiucal SKU/Product (as seen below).

```
    record_ID      week  store_id  sku_id  total_price  base_price  \
18         30  17/01/11      8095  222087     173.8500    192.3750   
39         55  17/01/11      8094  222087     210.9000    210.9000   
59         79  17/01/11      8063  222087     216.6000    216.6000   
79        106  17/01/11      8023  222087     169.5750    220.1625   
99        131  17/01/11      8058  222087     170.2875    210.9000   

    is_featured_sku  is_display_sku  units_sold  count_id_sku_store  ...  \
18                1               0         214               130.0  ...   
39                0               0          60               130.0  ...   
59                0               0          45               130.0  ...   
79                1               0         391               130.0  ...   
99                1               0         173               130.0  ...   

    price_store_id  price_sku_id  price_to_store_id  price_to_sku_id  week_1  \
18      225.480369    221.041554         210.667067        195.12901       1   
39      221.591154    221.041554         208.766611        195.12901       1   
59      220.264038    221.041554         209.705769        195.12901       1   
79      247.386525    221.041554         231.463063        195.12901       1   
99      237.061904    221.041554         220.944058        195.12901       1   

    week_num  week_num1  week_sin  week_cos  price_diff_percent  
18         1          1  0.120208  0.992749            0.096296  
39         1          1  0.120208  0.992749            0.000000  
59         1          1  0.120208  0.992749            0.000000  
79         1          1  0.120208  0.992749            0.229773  
99         1          1  0.120208  0.992749            0.192568
```

The two features i wish to focus on are **'week'** and **'units_sold'**.
I want to count the number of units sold in the week 17/01/11.

Refer to the data shown here:

```
            week  units_sold
18      17/01/11         214
39      17/01/11          60
59      17/01/11          45
79      17/01/11         391
99      17/01/11         173
         ...         ...
150080  09/07/13         268
150093  09/07/13         215
150106  09/07/13         178
150124  09/07/13         393
150141  09/07/13         204

[9360 rows x 2 columns]
```

But as you can see there are multiple indices of week 17/01/11.
I thus want to count the cumulative sum of sales in this week and do the same for other subsequent weeks. In other words how many sales did i get in week 17/01/11 or in week 16/02/11, etc, etc.
Can anyone help me with this?

Edit:

```
train.groupby('week')['units_sold'].cumsum()
Out[51]: 
0            20
1            48
2            67
3           111
4           163
 
150145    68013
150146    68043
150147    68074
150148    68086
150149    68101
```

Comment: Maybe you need a simple `groupby`. Can you please check `df.groupby('Week')['units_sold'].cumsum()` ?

Comment: Not if you use `groupby('week')` as @ShubhamSharma said.